# Is it possible to change the Target of an Action at runtime in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda, runtime, action, bind

I am trying to do something similar to javascript's function.bind() in c#.

I have an action:

```
var action = new Action(()=>{this.SomeProperty = 123;});
```

At runtime, I want to execute the action in a different closure so the instance "this" is a dynamic object.

something like this:

```
var action = new Action(()=>{this.SomeProperty = 123;});

dynamic myDynamic = new ExpandoObject();
myDynamic.SomeProperty=321;

action.Bind(myDynamic); <--Of course this does not work...

action.DynamicInvoke();

Console.WriteLine(myDynamic.SomeProperty); //Should write 123...
```

I am starting to think this is not possible given what I am learning about how the runtime works in regard to lambdas and dynamics.. Perhaps there is some way using reflection?

Thanks
Lance

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to do anything complicated, you just need to make an action taking a dynamic parameter.

```
Action<dynamic> method = new Action<dynamic>((obj) => obj.SomeProperty = 123);
```

You can then call the action with any number of objects (some will throw exceptions obviously if they cant set that property)

```
method(new ExpandoObject());
method(new object()); // exception
```

If you want to call it like your example, it would be as simple as making an extension method:

```
public static class DynamicActionExtensions
{
     public static void DynamicInvoke<T>(this T actual)
     {
          dynamic obj = actual;
          obj.SomeProperty = 123;
     }
}
```

EDIT: How about this:

```
public class Invoker
{
     protected List<dynamic> _objects = null;
     protected Action<dynamic> _method = null;

     public Invoker()
     {
         _objects = new List<dynamic>();
     }

     public void Bind(dynamic actual)
     {
          _objects.Add(actual);
     }

     public void SetDelegate<T>(Action<T> action)
     {
         _method = action; // should work due to covariant type assignment
     }

     public void DynamicInvoke()
     {
         _objects.ForEach(x => _method(x));
     }
}

Invoker x = new Invoker();
x.SetDelegate<SomeTypeForIntellisense>((obj) => obj.SomeProperty = 123);
x.Bind(new ExpandoObject());
x.DynamicInvoke();
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Matt.  The way you have illustrated is how I am doing it at the moment.  The problem is that I would like to have intellisense when the author is creating the action as they can be quite complex.  I know that Unit testing should alleviate any exceptions if the bound type does not have the correct property, but it would really simplify things from a development standpoint if the intellisense were available.

Comment: You want the consumer of the code to be able to specify the intellisense of the delegate to execute?

Comment: Hi Tejs, I don't know if I fully understand the question.  I have an action that is created within the scope of a typed class.  Therefore 'this' within the context of the anonymous lambda will be the class in which it was originally declared.  Later, when something else invokes the action, I would like to change the scope of this to a different dynamic object that exposes the same properties and methods of the original class, but in a dynamic way.  My thought is that I could then have my intellisense, and control the closure of the invocation at runtime to inject whatever I want.

Comment: Added another example to maybe give some inspiration

Comment: Well, my example wont work exactly because of how the delegates work, but the effect is basically figuring out how you can assign an Action<T> so that an Action<dynamic> can execute on it.

Comment: First of all Holy Cow Tejs, how do you type so fast.  Second of all that looks like it may work. I'll have to give it a try tomorrow and see if I can get it working with my project.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes Tejs, 'figuring out how you can assign an Action<T> so that an Action<dynamic> can execute on it' is what I need, also figuring out how to change the anonymous Action's scope would be awesome, but I am starting to think this is not possible.

Comment: `Action<T>` is *contra* variant, not *co* variant. That means you can't assign an `Action<T>` value to a variable of type `Action<dynamic>`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to change the target of an `Action`? No, because `Action` is immutable. However, you *can* relatively easily create a new delegate with the same method but a different target.

```
public static Action Bind(this Delegate d, object target)
{
    return (Action) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), target, d.Method);
}
```

This will work just fine for lambdas that don't capture variables:

```
        Action a = () => this.MyProperty = 12;
        a();
        var f = new Foo();
        var b = a.Bind(f);
        b();
        Console.WriteLine(this.MyProperty == f.MyProperty); // "True"
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to help you because you want to change the *type* of the target at runtime. Since the compiler bakes the type of the target into the delegate, there's no way to change it. And with `dynamic` it's even worse because it generates completely different code to access dynamic types.

If you're willing to limit yourself to what the compiler will generate in an `Expression<>`, you'd be able to do some complex expression tree manipulation and make it work. Since expression trees can't even have assignment operators, even your trivial example wouldn't be possible with this method.

I'm pretty sure that there's no way to both get Intellisense *and* be able to use runtime (dynamic) binding for anything that LINQ doesn't allow.

Comment: Yeah, when I was going to sleep last night, I was thinking of how it's nigh impossible to get both dynamic anything and intellisense.